# Deleting Users and their directories Would delete everything from my system?

Tags: uninstall, users, delete, user-management, reset

When I had joined my organization. I had installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 by fully removing its Windows installation. After regular upgrades and updates now it's been Ubuntu 15.04.
  Today, I am leaving my current organization and done with all handover stuff therefore I have to reset everything from my ubuntu. So that It should look like a fresh copy of Ubuntu (15.04).

i.e

- All the softwares that I had installed.
- All the users and groups that I had created
- All the files that I had created and modified...etc.

So, the query is

- Deleting users would do all above things? OR
- Is there anything else required?

Comment: Deleting all users will not remove all the software you installed.

Comment: @mchid -Thanks. Hmm, I thought so. Could you please tell me what needs to be done to reset everything?

Comment: well, you could always reinstall

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/

Comment: if you don't feel like downloading a full iso, use this instead http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Comment: @mchid - how much time, it would take with the mini?

Comment: For the download, about 10 to 20 seconds. For the full install, I'd give it at least an hour or two just to be safe including all the updates, etc.

Comment: BTW, that was 64bit so if you need 32 or i386, see here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it will be a rather big hassle to revert all changes to the system and eliminate all traces of use. As you're not wanting to keep anything, I would strongly suggest you to just do a reinstall. This will be faster.

---

Anyway, you asked for a manual removal of stuff, so I will also try to answer that. Note that I probably forgot something which might be left, or that you might easily delete a file too much and make the system unstable or unusable. No warranty on that.

---

- > All the software that I had installed

No, deleting your user account will not uninstall any system-wide software! If you have installed an application in your home directory though and you opt to delete the entire home directory, it will be gone. But all programs installed through the Software Center, Synaptic, `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `dpkg`, etc... will remain. You would have to uninstall them all manually.

A good start for finding out  what packages you installed is the output of:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

But prepare for a rather long list that contains also all preinstalled and system packages which you should not remove. Only uninstall those which you can remember to have installed yourself. This gets done most easily with:

```
sudo apt-get purge PACKAGENAMES
```

After that, also remove all no longer needed dependency packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---

- > All the users and groups that I had created

You can only manually remove user accounts. While doing this, depending on the tool you get the option to also delete the home directory of that user or maybe even all files owned by him anywhere (can take ages of time...). Some tools automatically remove the deleted user's primary group, if it became empty.

I would recommend you one of the following commands to remove users and their primary group and delete their home directory, depending if you want a backup archive of what got deleted or not:

```
sudo deluser --remove-home --backup USERNAME
sudo deluser --remove-home USERNAME
```

To remove a group, use the command below:

```
sudo delgroup GROUPNAME
```

---

- > All the files that I had created and modified...etc.

You could do this manually or modify the `deluser` commands above. Chose one of them (with or without creating a backup archive of the deleted files) and run it instead of those above. Depending on the number of files you have, this might take a good while though, so better run it before you start your lunch break.

```
sudo deluser --remove-all-files --backup USERNAME
sudo deluser --remove-all-files USERNAME
```

Or you can use `find` to search for all of your files:

```
sudo find /DIRECTORY/TO/SEARCH -user USERNAME
```

This will recursively search in `/DIRECTORY/TO/SEARCH` and its subdirectories for all files owned by `USERNAME`.

You can immediately delete all those files (*dangerous! - make sure you know the consequences, have backed up all your important data and checked the output of the `find` command above*) with the following command:

```
sudo find /DIRECTORY/TO/SEARCH -user USERNAME -delete
```

Note that both `find` and `deluser --remove-all-files` only spot files that are owned by a user. It's unimportant who created them.

Answer (score 1):

**Completely removing everything from your system and retaining a working OS**

From your question you started out with a fresh copy of Ubuntu by removing Windows and installing Ubuntu.  You did that with an ISO.  You replaced your Windows Partition (your Windows Installation with an Ubuntu installation).

You can do the same thing by replacing your current Ubuntu installation with a Fresh Ubuntu installation from a downloaded ISO.

When you perform the installation you'll have options such as upgrading, or only replacing the system directories such as (/etc, /lib, /var, etc).

Your best best would be to ensure you have backed up the system in case you are mistaken about wanting to remove everything you have installed including all the users and their files and documents.  Because if you do a complete fresh install this would be like virtually replacing the computer with a new computer where nothing from before will be there.

I would recommend that you install the latest "LTS" so that the installation you leave will have official Ubuntu support for a longer period of time (upto 5 years from release).

**Removing programs without Fresh OS Install**

An alternative would be to actually know which programs you have installed and individually remove each program one by one by name.  You would have to use the provided method of the program itself to remove it and it's associated files.

For programs you installed through the normal repository or a DEB package you can uninstall the individual programs with:

Programs install from the repository:

```
$ apt-get remove --purge packagename
```

Programs install from DEB packages:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r packagename
```

After you have removed each of the programs that you installed, then you could create a new default user with `sudo` access.  Log in from that account and remove/purge the user accounts that you want removed (including your own).

The -r option will delete the users home directory where has documents, downloads, and profiles are stored.

```
$ userdel -r vivek
```